# Field ClientService required a bean that could not be found in Spring

Tags: java, spring

This is my ClientService class :

```
public interface ClientService{
public void saveClient(Client client);
}
```

This is the implementation :

```
@Service("clientService")
public class ClientServiceImpl{
@Autowired
private ClientRepository clientRepository;

public void saveClient(Client client) {
    clientRepository.save(survey);
}}
```

This is my repository:

```
@Repository("clientRepository")
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long> { }
```

And in my controller I have :

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
@Autowired
private ClientService clientService;
```

which I then try to access 
    clientService.save in the function.

What annotation could I possibly be missing or what am I doing wrong ?
Cuz I've done this the same way before and it has worked for other services.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

I had forgotten implements ClientService in the ClientServiceImplementation class!